# X-Editable + Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, x-editable

***what I have:***

I change on of model attributes with help of *x-editable*.

***What I need:***

Check some conditions before make a change.

***What a problem:***

```
this.$el.find("#my-field").editable({
    type        : 'text',
    name        : myFieldTitle,
    value       : myCurrentValue,
    pk          : this.model.get('id'),
    url         : '',
    success     : function(response, newValue) {
        //PROBLEM: At this moment visual representation of a model has been already changed
        //no matter if condition is true or false
        if (condition)
          self.model.set(field.name, newValue);
    }
});
```

***Question:***

how can I change visual representation (of my model) with  help of *x-editable* **only after condition checking**?

Comment: above code examples doesn't reveal much, more code surrounding this would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the callback `validate` from X-Editable:

```
this.$el.find("#my-field").editable({
    [...]
    validate     : function(value) {

        if (condition)
          [...]
    }
});
```

Link: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable